# Visual Studio Workloads shared accros versions?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019, game-development, visual-studio-2022

The question I have is more to see if I'm able to save 25GB of hard drive space. I currently have 2022 Version of Visual Studio Community installed, though the engine I'm working in requires 2019 to be installed. how ever I have all the same required packages installed in 2022 version. (the engine for some reason does not want to use the newest version of VSC and is trying to force me to revert back) so if I install the previous version will the workloads installed with VSC 2022 be used in VSC 2019 or must I install the work loads independently of each VSC edition in order for me to use it properly ? If they are able to use the same workloads am i required to connect them in some way? if they are not able to read the same workloads, is there a way to get it use the same sources?

TIA.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio's installation is authored with two types of packages: "standalone" or shared packages, which are typically independent MSIs that are installed in a shared folder, or a component-specific location; and "per-instance" packages which are installed into the VS install location.

The former group is basically what you're asking for.  However, different versions of VS may install different versions of those shared packages (e.g. VS2022 may have a newer version of a standalone component than what VS2019 shipped with, and both will get installed).  The goal though is that as long as they use the same version, it will be shared.

The latter group is not shared, usually because they are tightly coupled to other Visual Studio components and attempting to re-use them across arbitrary versions of VS could lead to weird runtime behaviors.

So, to a large extent, VS does what you're trying to do, as much as it can (according to the people that create each component).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I have looked at the versions and they do indeed  have separate versions and i guess thats why i need to have them both installed. its a shame that some applications mandate a certain version rather than have a choice given to the user with set up options, I am currently unable to use the 2022 version of vs which is what i was hoping to achieve as the engine simply wont compile or open the code i want to access with out vs 2019 installed. thanks again. much appreciate the time for you to clear that up for me.